# Why docker not support the http api for docker stack?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-stack, portainer

I checked docker API doc:[api/v1.40](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.40/#operation/ServiceList) and I couldn't find API support for `docker stack` stuff.

After I googled it, I found these GitHub issues:

1. [Feature Req: docker stack deploy into API](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32476)
2. [Roadmap for `docker deploy` and Bundles](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/26876)

I still don't understand why `docker stack` stuff isn't supported.

If I want to manage my stack through HTTP API, what am I supposed to do?  It looks like I can only ssh to the machine in a certain way to execute commands `docker stack ls` if I want to list all stacks on my web management page.

Also, I'd like to know how a product like `portainer` achieves this function?

Any answer will be appreciated.

Comment: How about exposing docker through an [http socket](https://success.docker.com/article/how-do-i-enable-the-remote-api-for-dockerd)?

Comment: Yes I exposed it and I used http API to manage docker. But there is no api for stack.

Comment: Why won't you use k8s? It's far more superior.

Comment: k8s is too heavy for me

Comment: It's strange how docker client could list stacks, but there is no such API :) Do they get all services and extract all stack names from their labels and group them to make the stacks list?

Comment: Portainer does this by shipping the `docker` binary with the portainer image.